# Cutting a Banach-Tarski Cake

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, game-theory

I was reading a cake-cutting problem here (not really related, so I won't link to it), and for some reason, this variation occurred to me.  I have no idea whether this problem is even well-formed:

Alice and Bob have bought a cube-shaped cake, $10$ cm on a side.  Alice makes one ordinary linear cut dividing the cake into two ordinary parts (she does not separate the parts, however), and Bob selects a piece* that is a subset (not necessarily proper) of one of the two parts.  Continuing with Alice, they then take turns selecting pieces from the whole cake until the cake is entirely divvied up.

Each person's objective is to obtain pieces sufficient to be reassembled into a cube-shaped cake, $10$ cm on a side.  Can either person "win"?  Can both?  Note that I do not require the actual algorithm either person would follow (though I would be happy with one); I merely want to know if such an algorithm must exist.

*Assume that by "piece," we mean the usual definition of piece with respect to the Banach-Tarski paradox.

Comment: If I were Alice and I were to go first, I would simply take the entire cake, thereby giving me a cube-shaped cake, 10cm each side, and leaving Bob without any.

Comment: How is this game theory? They both play towards the same goal. It's like if we play chess in order to make let me win.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Sorry, yes, I had thought of that and made up an additional condition.  I then promptly (as is my wont) forgot about it.  I'll add that now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It's intended to be competitive, but now that I think of it, I might not be able to make it well-formed.  If I can without changing the statement too much, I will do so; otherwise, I might have to delete this (unless someone has any suggestions about how to better handle it).

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the rules of the game you're proposing.  On turn 1, Alice makes a linear cut to divide the cake into pieces $A$ and $B$, and then Bob chooses a subset of either $A$ or $B$ for himself.  What happens on turn 2?  Does Bob choose one of the remaining pieces and cut it again?  Does Alice choose a subset of one of the remaining pieces?

Comment: @EricWofsey: No, the next step is Alice selects a subset of the whole cake.  Alice's original cut was in place: She did not "separate" the pieces after her linear cut.

Comment: Why is the cutting step needed at all then?  Just to prevent Bob from claiming the entire cake immediately?

Comment: I've edited the question so as to make the question clearer (hopefully).  Apologies!

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes, see JMoravitz's first comment.

Comment: It is clear that either player can prevent the other from winning by just taking the entirety of what's left on some early turn.  So you probably want to add a rule saying that you aren't allowed to make a move that guarantees that you lose (unless you are already guaranteed to lose), or something similar.

Comment: So Alice cuts a line on the cake, and Bob takes a piece? How can you hope, with such Borel pieces to reconstruct the Banach-Tarski Banach-Tarski theorem? It's impossible.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I restated the question, so that their principal goal is to obtain a complete copy of the original cake for themselves.  They are no longer concerned with whether the other person does so as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Only Bob's initial selection is restricted to one side of the linear slice.  After that, starting with Alice, each person may take an arbitrary subset of the entire remainder of the cake.

Comment: As Asaf Karaglia has already noted,"ordinary linear cuts" will always result in Borel-measurable pieces of positive measure .

Comment: @user254665: I saw that, but only the first cut and selection is based on a linear cut.  After that, everything is a (possibly unmeasurable) subset.